# Geometry rounding problems: minimally disturbed plane messes up halfspace intersection

Tags: c++, geometry, cgal

I'm using CGAL and using their latest (https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/116) version of `halfspace_intersection_3`, which calculates the convex polyhedron whose points are on the negative of a number of planes.

After much debugging, I reduced the problem down to the following difference:

```
    planes.push_back(Plane(0,0,-1,0));
    planes.push_back(Plane(0,0,1,-116));
    planes.push_back(Plane(-1,0,0,-316));
    planes.push_back(Plane(1,0,0,264));
    planes.push_back(Plane(0,1,0,256));
    planes.push_back(Plane(0,-1,0,-448));
    planes.push_back(Plane(0/*or 5.71515e-17*/,0.635425,0.772162,161.125));
```

The planes are supposed to form a ramp-thing. Look at the a-value of the last plane. Setting it to `0` yields the left version. Setting it to `5.71515e-17` yields the right-hand (and incorrect) version.

[image]

The right-hand version suddenly has a facet that's not even planar anymore! In the correct geometry, everything is on the scale of `1e0` (including the small offset from the "ground"), and you'd think a tiny distortion such as `5.71515e-17` should not cause this to happen.

Now of course I can just guard against this by checking if some value is very close to 0 and set it to 0. But what if the object is non-axial?

Any suggestions on how to guard against this problem, or if it's a bug?

Comment: I see you also posted it to https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/233, which is good. But it would help to include a complete program that reproduces the issue. I don't know about others, but snippets where I have to reinvent the rest of the program make me move on to other issues.